# mousedown event in PIXI doesn't get triggered with creative pen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pixi.js, wacom, pen-tablet

I have an issue where I have a button on my `canvas` which works great when I use a regular mouse, but when I use my Wacom creative pen tablet the button seems to not work.

```
mainLayer.on("mousedown", () => start());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Chrome dev tools to set event breakpoints and see what actually gets triggered.

**To set breakpoints with chrome dev-tools:**

[image: Event breakpoints]

But my guess is that you use `mousedown` instead of `pointerdown`.

So, this should fix it:

```
mainLayer.on("pointerdown", () => start());
```

You can read more about the Interaction events Pixi supports here: [PIXI docs](http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.interaction.InteractionManager.html)

Comment: Yeah, it was actually the pointerdown event that got triggered. Works nice!